# Create a drop down in JQuery with PHP values

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have this code from the interwebs about how to duplicate a field in a form.
Now the problem is that this form is a text field, but I would like to have a drop down list with all pages from my website.

This would be easy if it only was in PHP since I don't know how to write jQuery

So is there anybody out there who is kind enough and willing to combine these two codes for me:

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var fieldname = <?php echo json_encode( $this->get_field_name('stream_sources') ) ?>;
        var fieldnum = <?php echo json_encode( $stream_counter-1 ) ?>;

        jQuery(function($) {
            var count = fieldnum;
            $('.<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'add_field' );?>').click(function() {
                $("#<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'field_clone' );?>").append("<p><input type='text' name='"+fieldname+"["+(count+1)+"][title] value='' class='widefat sourc"+(count+1)+"'><span class='remove-field button button-primary button-large'>Verwijderen</span></p>");
                count++;
            });
            $(".remove-field").live('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

With this PHP:

```
    <select name="meta-url-1" id="meta-url-1"><?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
    $posts = get_pages($args);
    echo '<option value="#"></option>';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Notice that the PHP is how I would write it. But I need to have the drop down in a repeatable field.

Hope this is possible && anyone would help.
M.

Comment: You want that,if your php values are repeating many times,then dropdown list also contain those repeated values,is it?

Comment: @rack_nilesh What? I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
<option value="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
```

In this case the value you are assigning in option will not repeat. You will need to assign a unique value to each option.

I suggest you to use a number variable to assign value.

Try below code:

```
<select name="meta-url-1" id="meta-url-1"><?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
    $posts = get_pages($args);
    $i = 0;
    echo '<option value="#"></option>';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i++; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: ThnQ for your reply. If you take a look at the JQuery you see that there is a counter running for the unique value. My problem is to combine the JQuery with the PHP. In a nutshell. The .append() in the JQuery should be replaced with the PHP drpodown